# When and how will the Chinese spacestation reenter?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, reentry, debris, space-station

China's first space station Tiangong-1 is expected to deorbit in late 2017. Are NASA or others tracking it? What is its position and condition at present time?

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/do-we-have-any-idea-when-tiangong-1-will-deorbit

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely being tracked, as everything in space large enough to do so, by [JSPOC](https://www.space-track.org/). They release all non-classified spacecraft locations as well.

When it will reenter, and even better, where, are much more difficult questions.

The exact time of it's reentry [can't be accurately predicted in advance](http://www.spacedaily.com/reports/Has_Tiangong_1_gone_rogue_999.html). Right now it is just under 400 km, which, while it will have a short lifespan, likely be less than a year, it won't reenter in the next month. So I predict between 6 months and a year to reenter, at a location that will only be known a few days in advance, if we are lucky. The exact orbit in which a satellite will reenter is very difficult to determine ahead of time, and even just 1 orbit difference could mean thousands of km difference in it's landing position.

At this time, it is believed that there is no control authority at all with the space station.

Answer (score 2):

For your viewing pleasure, the current position of Tiangong 1:

http://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=37820

Answer (score 0):

If you live more than 43 degrees north or south of the equator you won't get hit by it, it'll be constrained to somewhere within that band.